# Kentico 12: detect if an editable area contains any widgets

Tags: kentico, personalization, kentico-12, kentico-mvc, kentico-api

I'm building a site in Kentico 12 MVC and working on setting up content personalization. The normal way to do this is to add an [editable area](https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/developing-websites/page-builder-development/creating-pages-with-editable-areas-in-mvc) in the view:

```html
<div>
    @Html.Kentico().EditableArea("area1")
</div>
```

Then, in the CMS, the Page tab will show an empty area where the user can add a widget with personalized content.

The problem is that the content I want to personalize is located in my site's login box, which is a common element on every page, so I'd need to manually add a widget into the editable area on *every page* individually. But my site has over 300 pages, so that's totally impractical.

Is there a way from within my view model that I could check if the editable area has any widgets, and if it doesn't, output default content instead? I'm trying to see if there's an API method or something that would let me count the number of widgets inside an editable area, but I can't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to check with regex  if Editable area html contains widget tag `"<object type="widget" >"`

Comment: I don't see that anywhere...? If the editable area doesn't contain any widgets, then it just renders as an empty `<div>`. If it does, then the `<div>` will wrap the HTML of whatever widget has been added. I don't see an `<object>` element anywhere.

Comment: nope it does not work for mvc model :(, works for portal only. I think all widgets json are stored in DocumentPageBuilderWidgets field, i.e in SQL:  SELECT DocumentPageBuilderWidgets, documentid, *  from  view_cms_tree_joined  where nodealiaspath = '/Home'. You can do the same with DocumentHelper - but it will produce a query. It should be a better way.